# Migrating database from local development to Heroku-Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, django-database

After establishing a database using `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev`, I tried to migrate my local database to heroku database. So I first ran

`heroku python manage.py migrate`. After that I created a dump file of my local database using `pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser mydb > mydb.dump`. I uploaded my `mydb.dump` file to dropbox and then used the following command to load the dump to my heroku database

```
 heroku pg:backups restore'https://www.dropbox.com/s/xkc8jhav70hgqfd/mydb.dump?' HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COLOR_URL
```

But, that throws the following error -

```
 r004 ---restore---> HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PURPLE
 [0KRunning... 0.00B..
 [0KAn error occurred and your backup did not finish.
 Please run `heroku pg:backups info r004` for details.
```

And on running `heroku pg:backups info r004` I get -

```
Database:    BACKUP
Started:     2015-06-25 18:19:37 +0000
Finished:    2015-06-25 18:19:38 +0000
Status:      Failed
Type:        Manual
Backup Size: 0.00B
=== Backup Logs
2015-06-25 18:19:38 +0000: waiting for restore to complete
2015-06-25 18:19:38 +0000: pg_restore: [archiver] did not find magic string in file header
2015-06-25 18:19:38 +0000: restore done
2015-06-25 18:19:38 +0000: waiting for download to complete
2015-06-25 18:19:38 +0000: download done
```

There is not much information on this error online and I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: how big is the database?

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli 7.4mb. I've got a free heroku account. Is the database size too much?

Comment: The problem may actually be somewhere completely different: Dropbox is usually not offering the raw file on that link. Instead it is serving a download page. Add a `?raw=1` to the end of the URL to retrieve the raw file and use with  heroku pg:backups.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If the database is small and you feel lucky this might do it

```
pg_dump --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser myd | heroku pg:psql
```

Comment: It worked. Wonder why the statement I was using didn't work since that is what heroku docs recommends for importing database.

Comment: You are a life saver dude.

Comment: i get Error: Missing required flag with this cmd

Answer (score 9):

I've had this error too and my solution was a little different. The problem was related to the format used. I needed to use --format=c when dumping the db.

To solve it I dumped the db again using --format=c

```
pg_dump --no-acl --no-owner --format=c database_name > db.dump
```

Then importing it to my heroku app

```
heroku pg:backups restore 'url_for_db.dump' DATABASE_URL
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: I literally just logged in so I could upvote you and comment. This saved my bacon and was the solution for me. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: "--format=c " that is what was missing, perfect, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use :
`heroku pg:push mylocaldb HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA --app sushi`

source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-push

Answer (score 1):

For windows users;

`heroku pg:backups:restore "https://s3.amazonaws.com/me/items/3H0q/mydb.dump" DATABASE_URL`

According to the official docs, be sure to use double-quotes around the remote url if you're using windows. [see official docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import)